# Dimiss location service alert using code

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-location

I am using Core Location API for one my Cocoa application. With every application launch, it throws an alert asking for user permission for location services. I want to use the location services but with each application launch I do not want user to give permissions. Is there any way to dismiss this alert from code and still have the lat/long co-ordinates returned.

Comment: are you testing this on the device or in the simulator?

Comment: This is a MAC application. I am running this on MAC machine.

Comment: It shouldn't prompt you for location all the time. Once the user selects it, it will save it in UserDefaults, and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

[I did a bit of research on devforums for you](http://devforums.apple.com/thread/162285) and if you run your app ***outside*** of Xcode, it shouldn't ask you for authorization each and every time.